# html or css to adjust and format the width of a blog post

Tags: html, css

I am having some difficulty with code on my website. Right now my blog post text goes across the entire width of the content page and is centered.

I would like the text to be left aligned, have equal margins on each side, and make the width of the blog content narrower so there are fewer characters per line..exactly like this [example blog post](https://cupofjo.com/2018/04/advice-stories-on-grief-loss/)

I'm looking to make every blog post this same format, but everything I have tried does not seem to work? I'm not sure what css/html I should change or add. I've tried box-sizing, justify as well as adjusting the margins but it doesn't give me this result I'm looking for and I'm not sure what steps to take. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Please add the code you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

You should create new `<div id="test">` element and put your text inside it. Add following CSS for that div:

```
#test{
width: 680px; /* adding width of text field */
margin: 0 auto; /* centering it */
text-align: left; /* aligning text to left side */

font-size: 15px; /* size of your font */
line-height: 24px; /* space between two lines */
letter-spacing: -0.01em; /* space between two letters */
/* By playing with values of last 3 lines you can make text look exactly how you want, I tried to mimic site that you posted as much as I could (I c/p-ed their CSS for text) */
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me with this! It worked perfectly. I really appreciate it. I need to learn more and this really clarified things for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bootstrap classes for this. It will really help you alot. 
Its' container class will give you equal margin both side 
(you can see example here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/ )

and it's grid classes will help you in setting your left and right sections (see the link https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/).

Hope this will help you.